# image slide left to right bottom of the corner jquery

Tags: jquery, image, slide

I am trying to slide image left to right bottom of the corner.

I am using this code but js not supported (direction ) paramerer..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {            
        $("#man").show("slide", {
        direction: "down"
    }, 2000);


    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #man {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: this code is working.                                                                          <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
               
        $(window).load(function () {
            $("#man").show("slide", {
                direction: "Down"
            }, 2000);
        });

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #man {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

you can use **.animate()**  with **max-height**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {            
         $("#man").animate({
            'max-height': "500px"
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #man {
        /*display: none;*/ no need 
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        max-height : 0px;
    }
</style>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2tjkbtco/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The [slideToggle](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwijyrnigIzGAhXuL4wKHSPGBHw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fslidetoggle%2F&ei=xch7VePTOe7fsASjjJPgBw&usg=AFQjCNEDd4QJ1hDmLY7AHbzO6rzmFKQ_8w&sig2=LMI3jZWSvhGRKiL-1m54jw&bvm=bv.95515949,d.cWc) method does this pretty easily.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/50nxLqxx/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="man"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
     $("#man").slideToggle(500);
});
```

**CSS**

```
#man {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).load(function () {
            $("#man").show("slide", {
                direction: "Down"
            }, 2000);
        });

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #man {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }
    </style>
```